# link_to with controller_name and action name not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations

I'm working on upgrading rails 3.2 app to rails 4.2. I have stuck with one issue. link_to with controller and action name not working

```
<%= link_to "Login", :controller => "user", :action => "login" %>
```

This is the link I want to convert into rails 4 code. using the same fashion.

I have tried this way.

```
<%= link_to "Login", { controller: "user", action: "login" } %>
```

its gives be below error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)
```

Is anyone faced this issue. I have google this but not solved this.

Comment: Leave the code as is. Rails 4.x doesn't require the `key: value` syntax.

Comment: I have solved this issue. actually I am using  gem 'bartt-ssl_requirement' which is causing this issue. Thanks for Sebastián Palma and MZaragoza for your help.

Comment: You can accept the answer @AjinathJedhe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking at the documentation  https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

```
<%= link_to "Profile", controller: "profiles", action: "show", id: @profile %>
# => <a href="/profiles/show/1">Profile</a>
```

you should be able to do

```
<%= link_to "Login",  controller: "user", action: "login" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the `controller` and `action` as options, not within a hash:

```
<%= link_to 'Login', controller: 'user', action: 'login' %>
```

Or also you can check the specific route for Users#login and pass it as the second option.